# How do you do with sailsjs a query with '$in'

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a collection with that :

```
{name : 'hello', tags : ['foo', 'bar']}
,{name : 'world', tags : ['space', 'bar']}
,{name : 'galaxy', tags : ['foo', 'space']}

    ,attributes: {
        ,name: {
            type: 'STRING'
            ,required : 'string'
        }

        ,tags: {
            type: 'ARRAY'
            ,required : 'array'
        }
    }


};
```

i try that, but it doesn't work :

```
myCollection.find().where({tags: ['space' ,'foo']});s
```

How do you do for to search all items with a specific tag ?

thanks you

Comment: I'll dive into this as soon as I get my hands on my personal dev machine. In the meantime you could dabble into the Waterline query language documented here: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md

Answer (score 0):

Waterline interprets `myCollection.find().where({tags: ['space' ,'foo']});` as "find all where tags is *one* of `'space', 'foo'`"; it doesn't do fancy array intersection.  You'll need to access the native adapter methods for this.  Assuming you're using Mongo, it would be:

```
myCollection.native(function(err, collection) {

   collection.find({tags:{'$in':['space','foo']}}).toArray(function(err, results) {

     // Do something with results

   });

});
```

Docs on native Mongo adapter [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#documentation).